# Can't resolve website using Google's public dns

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, dnssec

I can't seem to be able access my site: yippie.nl, using Google's public DNS 8.8.8.8. Other DNS's work fine.

Could this be due to DNSKEY? Cause Route53 doesn't provide it.

http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=yippie.nl shows:

> Inconsistent security for yippie.nl - DS found at parent, but no
>   DNSKEY found at child.
>
> The parent has a secure delegation to the child (indicated by DS RRset
>   at the parent), but the child has no DNSKEY. This is probably due to a
>   previously signed zone that became unsigned without requesting the
>   parent to remove the secure delegation.

That's the only thing i could find.

When i do dig +trace +add yippie.nl I do get the full thing:
Ends:

```
yippie.nl.      300 IN  A   94.75.224.2
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: I had once similar problem - it was because nameservers for the given domain gave were not properly synchronized. I would suggest checking DNS records for the given domain on ALL domain's nameservers.

Comment: @AlešKrajník, unsure how to do that on route 53. everything seems fine on that end, it really seems like dnssec issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain have **`DS`** record (at it's parent zone):

```
dig yippie.nl DS
;; ANSWER SECTION:
yippie.nl.      7181    IN  DS  47534 8 2 07DF0CFD5F01119819B8319F7FEE01F7B8121EA11AB5BDEA765F5396 BB5B9CD1
```

, and haven't **`DNSKEY`** record:

```
dig yippie.nl DNSKEY
(no answer section)
```

And, it is not signed with DNSSEC (no RRSIG records).

Google public DNS checks DNSSEC and since your domain claims to have DNSSEC (DS record), 
but really is not signed, any DNSSEC-aware resolver consider it bogus. Most DNS resolvers today still ignore DNSSEC but google is one of whose who already started to check DNSSEC.

Verisign provides a very handy [DNSSEC-checking tool](http://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/yippie.nl)

To fix the situation, either

1. Remove the **`DS`** record for your domain from the parent zone.
2. Make the zone properly signed with **`DNSKEY`** that corresponds to the **`DS`** record
   you already have. (Amazon Route 53 [does not support DNSSEC](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#DNSSEC) thus you 
   will have to either host the zone on your own, or use another provider.)
   In any case, you can do it only if you posses a key that corresponds to the existing DS.
3. Sign the zone with a new DNSKEY, and replace the curent DS record with  the one 
   which corresponds to the DNKSEY you use. See [my video guide here](https://www.net-me.net/faq#enable-dnssec) (*refers to a proprietary service I'm affiliated with*.)

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to go for option 2: switching provider. Dynect offered to help me out with it. Thanks!

Comment: @MauriceKroon probably what you do with your new provider is "option 3" in my list. (_...you can do it (option 2), only if you posses a key that corresponds to the existing DS._ And I guess you don't).